# define variable PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON in windows using pycharm

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I use the pyCharm program for pySpark. I want to use this variable:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
```

in windows. Of course, I apply these variables directly to pyCharm like this:

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

and I have no problem , but want to use these variables:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
```

in **Environemt variables** in **Windows** directly. how can I use this.
thanks to help

Comment: You need to save those in an env file and reference the env inside the main file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `python.exe` is in a path that contains spaces. That confuses pyspark on Windows.

Just make sure your `python.exe` is in the PATH variable, and then simply declare `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python.exe` (no spaces, relative path) and that will make it work.